# Rename a stream of JSON entities

Tags: r, json, key, jq

I have  a stream of JSON entities. Here is one of them called 'info':

```
null
null
{
  "id": "qwefhu214o",
  "number": "2346",
  "date": "28.01.2019"
}
null
null
{
  "id": "esg324lif",
  "number": "1378",
  "date": "29.05.2019"
}
{
  "id": "gwrs853sdf",
  "number": "4487",
  "date": "20.12.2019"
}
```

I want to extract keys from nested json, so it looks like this:

```
null
null
{
  "info_id": "qwefhu214o",
  "info_number": "2346",
  "info_date": "28.01.2019"
}
null
null
{
  "info_id": "esg324lif",
  "info_number": "1378",
  "info_date": "29.05.2019"
}
{
  "info_id": "gwrs853sdf",
  "info_number": "4487",
  "info_date": "20.12.2019"
}
```

I try this, but it doesn't work:

```
jqr::jq('.[].info |= with_entries(.key |= "info_" + .)')
```

Its says:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       NA
                     (right here) ------^
```

I guess it because of NULLs. How could i do that? Should i put somewhere "?" in code ? That code works for cases when there are np NULLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "nested JSON" shown is actually a stream of JSON entities,
for which the following filter will produce the desired results:

```
if . then with_entries(.key |= "info_" + .) else . end
```

You can easily modify this filter as required.